# SQL Update column with another table column

Tags: join, update, postgresql-9.4

I'm using Postgres 9.4, and already seen others asking the same (simple) question, but theirs answers do not solved my problem and I can't see why. Suppose that I have these table A with common data and what type these data correspond, and consequently, a indicator (which I want to add that is in another table B):

```
 gid, type,  indicator
    1       a      ''
    2       b      ''
    3       e      ''
    4       a      ''
    5       d      ''
```

And this table B, which describes types and their respectives indicators

```
 type, indicator
    a       alfa
    b       alfa
    c       beta
    d       beta
    e       gama
```

I'm doing this query, but getting `indicator`=alfa for every row.

```
UPDATE A
SET    indicator = B.indicator
FROM   B
JOIN   A aa ON B.type = aa.type
```

The result that I was looking for A is something like this:

```
 gid, type,  indicator
    1       a      alfa
    2       b      alfa
    3       e      gama
    4       a      alfa
    5       d      beta
```

Hope that was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Update Syntax for PostgreSQL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-update.html) is different:

```
[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) |
          ( column_name [, ...] ) = ( sub-SELECT )
        } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_list ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

In your case please try the below query:

```
UPDATE TableA AS A
SET indicator = B.indicator 
FROM TableB AS B
WHERE B.type = A.type
```

Result:

```
gid     type    indicator
--------------------------
1       a       alfa
2       b       alfa
3       e       gama
4       a       alfa
5       d       beta
```

SQLFiddle [working DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/325ff/9)

Comment: Ok you're right. It works with fake data, but with my real data (it's the same structure), it just putting one value of indicator, like, just gama is been updated. See, there is a natural join between A and B after your `update` statement: http://prntscr.com/bpt6ut. It's in portuguese, but with many cognates for types and indicators. You can see why AMEACA  is not with CCIP indicator, for an example?

Comment: @AdelsonDias: Could you create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for the same _(with two table actual entries)_, it will helpful to solve the issue.

Comment: @Arulkmar Ok it' working fine... When I was copying  to SQLFiddle I noted that type indicator has a space after, like 'a ', needing a trim() to fix it. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: @AdelsonDias: Oh, glad to help.